# How to set a remote django develop environment？

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, webserver, remote-access

I have to set a development environment on a ubuntu machine(16.04).

It's django+postgresql+Nginx, I.think I could install all these things together on that machine，but I totally don't have any idea about how to connect it by using pycharm running on my pc, and how to manipulate the database.

Is there anyone could tell me how to connect it. This is the first time I have to use a remote machine.

By the way, my pc and ubuntu machine are in the same LAN, but there is another person who were asked to write db are not.

I hope I could get some suggestions from the community.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and common way is to use [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) you can find an official guide on how to enable SSH server on Ubuntu 16.04

You can use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) to connect from Windows PC to your SSH server or if you're using Mac or Linux, there should be already installed SSH client. So, just `ssh username@servername`

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH. Assuming you're on Linux, open a terminal and type:

```
ssh username@local-ip-address-of-machine
```

and then type your password when prompted. Your terminal window essentially acts as a terminal on your remote machine. From here, I suggest you research Docker in order to set up a custom environment for your Django project. I have only told you how to connect since that's your question, and there are plenty of tutorials on setting up Django and Docker. If the other person wants to connect, you will need to port forward on your router port 22 on the local IP of the machine.

If you haven't got SSH set up, [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) tells you how.